# What is the word for accepting help from someone else, not by merit, but because they know you?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, questions

So, say that someone is about to start at a new school, and your sister says "Oh, I aced that class! Let me introduce you to the teacher; maybe he'll give you less homework/give you more opportunities."

For some reason the word "hedonism" is rattling around in my brain, though I know that's not it. Also maybe it's the opposite of "altruism"? I'm having an off day and can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Nevermind guys, it came to me. Nepotism!

Comment: @Kimmie Why not post that as an answer (there should be an "Answer your Question" button in the bottom left), along with a link to a dictionary definition of nepotism?